# How do I access my SSH public key?

Tags: git, ssh, rsa

I've just generated my RSA key pair, and I wanted to add that key to GitHub.

I tried `cd id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa.pub`, but no luck. How can I access my SSH public key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find my RSA key fingerprint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607295/how-do-i-find-my-rsa-key-fingerprint)

Comment: @kenorb You mean that Q is a duplicate of this? This question was asked two years earlier. :)

Comment: Yes, the other seems to be better positioned (based on the wording, etc.), it has more views and votes within shorter period of time which indicates it's much more popular. See: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/191655) Once duplicate, both answers could be merged into one.

Comment: `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` worked for me! Check this [GitHub article](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

Answer (score 1546, accepted):

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`

You can list all the public keys you have by doing:

`$ ls ~/.ssh/*.pub`

Comment: Even though I see the file in the place it's referring to (C:/Users/Me/.ssh/.id_rsa.pub), these commands are producing an error: No such file or directory. I'm doing this from Git Bash, MyPC ~/.ssh

Comment: @sscirrus: In windows, you can use `type` command. Or just open the .pub file in notepad and paste it to github.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, for the answer and the edit. Make it an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: @sscirrus: accept this one ... it works as well (under unix or cygwin)

Comment: on Mac OS X: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: On Windows too, it's just `id_rsa.pub`, not *`.`*`id_rsa.pub`

Comment: @laggingreflex I've updated the answer to be clearer

Comment: On a Mac, you can do this to copy it to your clipboard (like cmd + c so that you can cmd + v to paste)
cat ~/Desktop/ded.html | pbcopy
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: `$` in `$ ls ~/.ssh/*.pub` was not required on my Mac.

Comment: if `ls ~/.ssh/*.pub` display nothing you need to generate your public key first. This was my issue on new machine.

Comment: Generate one if ssh key is not there already. As mentioned in one of the response.

Answer (score 297):

Copy the key to your clipboard.

```
$ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
# Copies the contents of the id_rsa.pub file to your clipboard
```

> Warning: it's important to copy the key exactly without adding
> newlines or whitespace. Thankfully the pbcopy command makes it easy to
> perform this setup perfectly.

and paste it wherever you need.

More details on the process, check: [**Generating SSH Keys**](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xclip -y` for those users who doesn't have `pbcopy` working.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y xclip` followed by `alias pbcopy="xclip -sel clip"` and then `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` OR simply `xclip -selection clipboard < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: I'm getting the error "pbcopy: command not found".

Answer (score 67):

You may try to run the following command to show your RSA fingerprint:

```
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -l'
```

or public key:

```
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -L'
```

If you've the message: 'The agent has no identities.', then you've to generate your RSA key by `ssh-keygen` first.

Comment: This is good for when you don't know the path of the key beforehand. It's not always in `~/.ssh/`.

Comment: Tried it out, works on Mac, Win10 (in git bash) and Ubuntu.

Comment: Using `ssh-add -L` is by far the better option as not every SSH key is an RSA key sitting in the `~/.ssh` folder. I much prefer to use my PGP key for authentication and so I do not have a `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file at all.

Answer (score 39):

If you're on Windows use the following, select all, and copy from a Notepad window:

```
notepad ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you're on OS X, use:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 30):

Mac, Ubuntu, Linux compatible machines, use this command to print public key, then copy it:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 21):

Here's how I found mine on OS X:

1. Open a terminal
2. (You are in the home directory) `cd .ssh` (a hidden directory)
3. pbcopy < id_rsa.pub (this copies it to the clipboard)

If that doesn't work, do an `ls` and see what files are in there with a `.pub` extension.

Answer (score 16):

On terminal `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

**explanation**

1. **cat** is a standard Unix utility that reads files and prints output
2. **~** Is your Home User path
3. **/.ssh** - your hidden directory contains all your ssh certificates
4. **id_rsa.pub** OR **id_dsa.pub** are RSA public keys, (the private key located on the client machine). the primary key for example can be used to enable cloning project from remote repository securely to your client end point.

Answer (score 13):

After you generate your SSH key you can do:

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub |pbcopy
```

which will copy your ssh key into your clipboard.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Windows PowerShell, the easiest way is to:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_<key-type-here>.pub | clip
```

That will copy the key to your clipboard for easy pasting.

So, in my instance, I use ed25519 since RSA is now fairly hackable:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip
```

---

Because I find myself doing this a lot, I created a function and set a simple alias I could remember in my PowerShell profile (learn more about PowerShell profiles [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx). Just add this to your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`:

```
function Copy-SSHKey {
    Get-Content ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip
}

Set_Alias -Name sshkey -Value Copy-SSHKey
```

Then, in a PowerShell console, run `. $profile` to load the functions. Then from now on all you will need to do is run `sshkey`, and then paste the key into wherever you need via the clipboard.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using windows, the command is:

```html
type %userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

it should print the key (if you have one). You should copy the entire result.
If none is present, then do:

```html
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your.email@example.com" -b 4096
```

Answer (score 10):

If you only have your **private** key available, you can generate the public key from it:

```
ssh-keygen -y
```

or

```
ssh-keygen -y -f path/to/private_key
```

Answer (score 9):

It is very simple. After you generated ssh key on your computer, you can access your public ssh key by following command

```
 cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You should see output similar to the following:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCyVGaw1PuEl98f4/7Kq3O9ZIvDw2OFOSXAFVqilSFNkHlefm1iMtPeqsIBp2t9cbGUf55xNDULz/bD/4BCV43yZ5lh0cUYuXALg9NI29ui7PEGReXjSpNwUD6ceN/78YOK41KAcecq+SS0bJ4b4amKZIJG3JWmDKljtv1dmSBCrTmEAQaOorxqGGBYmZS7NQumRe4lav5r6wOs8OACMANE1ejkeZsGFzJFNqvr5DuHdDL5FAudW23me3BDmrM9ifUzzjl1Jwku3bnRaCcjaxH8oTumt1a00mWci/1qUlaVFft085yvVq7KZbF2OPPbl+erDW91+EZ2FgEi+v1/CSJ5 your_username@hostname
```

Also note that the public key begins with ssh-rsa and ends with your_username@hostname.

Answer (score 8):

The following command will save the SSH key on the clipboard. You only need to paste at the desired location.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

Comment: This is my favourite way.

Answer (score 7):

Open your id_dsa.pub or some_name.pub file with gedit and copy-paste the contents!

Just use:

```
~/.ssh$ gedit some_name.pub
```

Comment: When i do so, its opening a blank file. Its not showing any text in it. But when i browse through file manager, i'm able to see the text.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
# sudo su
# cd /home/user/.ssh
.ssh# gedit id_rsa.pub
```

Then copy the entire file without any spaces. Click your icon at the top right of the GitHub page, go to settings, and add ssh.

Paste the copy into the space. It may prompt for your GitHub password. Enter it. Save.

Answer (score 7):

In UBUNTU +18.04

```
         ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
```

And After that Just Copy And Paste

```
         cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

or

```
         cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

Answer (score 6):

It can be found on this path (default path):

```
/Users/john/.ssh
```

`john` is your Mac username.

Answer (score 3):

> Open terminal
>   nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a new perspective to that question, if you use github, you could find your public key at: [https://github.com/${USERNAME}.keys](https://github.com/$%7BUSERNAME%7D.keys)

Answer (score 3):

`id_rsa.pub` is not a directory so you can not use `cd` to open it.

instead you can use the command `cd ~/.ssh` to access the folder containing your keys, then use `cat id_rsa.pub`, `nano id_rsa.pub` or `gedit id_rsa.pub` to access the key file.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, you can do this to copy it to your clipboard (like `cmd + c` shortcut)
`cat ~/Desktop/ded.html | pbcopy`
`pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

and to paste
`pbpaste > ~Documents/id_rsa.txt`

or, use `cmd + v` shorcut
to paste it somewhere else.

`~/.ssh` is the same path as `/Users/macbook-username/.ssh`
You can use Print work directory: `pwd` command on terminal to get the path to your current directory.

Answer (score 2):

I use Git Bash for my Windows.

$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)  //activates the connection

- some output

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa  //adds the identity

- some other output

$ clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub   //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT ONE. This adds your key to your clipboard. Go back to GitHub and just paste it in, and voilá! You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac/unix and Windows:

`ssh-keygen` then follow the prompts. It will ask you for a name to the file (say you call it pubkey, for example). 
Right away, you should have your key fingerprint and your key's randomart image visible to you.

Then just use your favourite text editor and enter command `vim pubkey.pub` and it (your ssh-rsa key)  should be there.

Replace vim with emacs or whatever other editor you have/prefer.

Comment: even though I cannot find the file on terminal or finder, opening the file with text editor works... thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-add` is used to show the public key.

`man ssh-add`

```
-L  Lists public key parameters of all identities currently repre‐
    sented by the agent.
```

On my Linux system I copy it using `xclip`

```
ssh-add -L | xclip
```

Comment: Hi manero :) Welcome! There are already a number of answers arond the usage of `ssh-add`,  could you provide more specifics that would make your Answer more unique? It may otherwise get flagged as a duplicate answer (not a bad thing, just a tidy up process in stackoverflow). Having said that I would suggest checking all existing answers for any overlap in your thinking in the future. Happy StackOverflowing!