# Calculate RSA key fingerprint

Tags: github, ssh, rsa, ssh-keys

I need to do the SSH key audit for GitHub, but I am not sure how do find my RSA key fingerprint. I originally followed a guide to generate an SSH key on Linux.

What is the command I need to enter to find my current RSA key fingerprint?

Comment: For all those using Linux who "keep coming back to this page", copy this to your bashrc: `function fingerprint() {
  ssh-keygen -lf $1 -E md5
}` Then (after you source the bashrc) you can get a fingerprint with `fingerprint ~/.ssh/key_file`

Comment: For those trying @JeffDiederiks function and wondering why it isn't working, Bash functions need a trailing `;` in the body, so use `function fingerprint() { ssh-keygen -lf $1 -E md5; }` instead.

Answer (score 1516, accepted):

Run the following command to retrieve the SHA256 fingerprint of your SSH key (`-l` means "list" instead of create a new key, `-f` means "filename"):

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/ssh/key
```

So for example, on my machine the command I ran was (using RSA public key):

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
2048 00:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (RSA)
```

To get the GitHub (MD5) fingerprint format with newer versions of ssh-keygen, run:

```
$ ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf <fileName>
```

Bonus information:

`ssh-keygen -lf` also works on `known_hosts` and `authorized_keys` files.

To find most public keys on Linux/Unix/OS X systems, run

```bash
$ find /etc/ssh /home/*/.ssh /Users/*/.ssh -name '*.pub' -o -name 'authorized_keys' -o -name 'known_hosts'
```

(If you want to see inside other users' homedirs, you'll have to be root or sudo.)

The `ssh-add -l` is very similar, but lists the fingerprints of keys added to your agent. (OS X users take note that magic passwordless SSH via Keychain is not the same as using ssh-agent.)

Comment: How do I find what is the path?

Comment: Also, if you simply want the public key, run: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Since your example hex fingerprint is 32 digits I believe it would be an MD5 fingerprint, correct? As opposed to a 40 digit fingerprint, which would indicate SHA1

Comment: On non-Ubuntu systems the relevant file may be in /etc/ssh, e.g. /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

Comment: Copy the long version (what you give to Github or Digital Ocean etc) to xclip with `xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. If you don't have xclip do `sudo apt-get install xclip` first

Comment: FYI, on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard): `ssh-keygen -lf /private/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`.

Comment: Worth noting that the fingerprint should be the same for both keys in a public / private keypair; so the fingerprint of `.ssh/id_rsa` should be the same as the one for `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. So, you can use either one (and, if you're like me and love tab-completion, it makes the job take 2 fewer keystrokes. Efficiency!).

Comment: If you're comparing against fingerprints listed in the AWS console, this will save you time... https://serverfault.com/questions/603982/why-does-my-openssh-key-fingerprint-not-match-the-aws-ec2-console-keypair-finger

Comment: @Zorawar, even ubuntu now is `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

Comment: You can also just type `ssh-keygen -l`. It will then ask you for the file and will suggest your public key if present. This way you don't need to type the path yourself.

Comment: The command you gave to "Find most public on a Linux/Unix/OSX system" was **super** helpful! My rsa key on a Raspberry Pi for instance is found in: `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

Comment: This answer is outdated. Use ssh-keygen -lf  -E md5 to get what OP wants.

Answer (score 728):

The newer SSH commands will list fingerprints as a ***SHA256*** Key.

For example:

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub 
1024 SHA256:19n6fkdz0qqmowiBy6XEaA87EuG/jgWUr44ZSBhJl6Y (DSA)
```

If you need to compare it against an old fingerprint you also need to specify to use the ***MD5*** fingerprint hashing function.

```
ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
2048 MD5:4d:5b:97:19:8c:fe:06:f0:29:e7:f5:96:77:cb:3c:71 (DSA)
```

Also available: `-E sha1`

Update...  YES...yes... I know...  DSA keys for SSH should no longer be used, the older RSA key or newer ecliptic keys should be used instead.

To those 'admins' that keep editing the command I used in the above.   STOP CHANGING IT!  You make the command and resulting output mis-match!

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that you can tell `ssh` to show you the server's old MD5 fingerprint using `ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5 example.org`, as mentioned [in this answer](http://superuser.com/a/929567/294963). (I was just searching for that, and this answer led me to that one, so I figure others might have a similar experience.)

Comment: This answer is most helpful for those wishing to compare their keys with what github.com shows (ie the MD5 formatted in hex)

Comment: Also very helpful for what comparing against what putty will report.

Comment: Currently GitHub shows the former format. By the way, in my case the SHA256 generated on my local key doesn't match with that one sent by GitHub! Is that an MITM? Even if I know it is, what am I supposed to do about it?

Comment: I was looking for this, because in Centos 7 and Centos 8 the defaults are different!

Answer (score 30):

To see your key on Ubuntu, just enter the following command on your terminal:

`ssh-add -l`

You will get an output like this:
`2568 0j:20:4b:88:a7:9t:wd:19:f0:d4:4y:9g:27:cf:97:23` yourName@ubuntu (RSA)

If however you get an error like; `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`
Then it means that ssh-agent is not running. You can start/run it with: 
       `ssh-agent bash` (thanks to @Richard in the comments) and then re-run `ssh-add -l`

Comment: If you're not on Ubuntu you might get this unfortunately "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Comment: This only works if you have the authentication agent running.

Comment: To get the authentication agent running you can use `ssh-agent bash` and proceed with life. In life as always; `ssh-agent` isn't guaranteed as a consistent implementation on all systems.

Comment: Another tip for linux; The option -F (dump fingerprint) of ssh-keygen-g3 will display the fingerprint of the key:  $ ssh-keygen-g3 -F /path/to/keyfile.pub  https://answers.ssh.com/questions/494/how-to-check-host-key-or-user-public-key-fingerprint

Answer (score 20):

A key pair (the private and public keys) will have the same fingerprint; so in the case you can't remember which private key belong to which public key, find the match by comparing their fingerprints.

The most voted answer by Marvin Vinto provides the fingerprint of a *public* SSH key file. The fingerprint of the corresponding *private* SSH key can also be queried, but it requires a longer series of step, as shown below.

1. Load the SSH agent, if you haven't done so. The easiest way is to invoke

   ```
   $ ssh-agent bash
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ ssh-agent tcsh
   ```

   (or another shell you use).
2. Load the private key you want to test:

   ```
   $ ssh-add /path/to/your-ssh-private-key
   ```

   You will be asked to enter the passphrase if the key is password-protected.
3. Now, as others have said, type

   ```
   $ ssh-add -l
   1024 fd:bc:8a:81:58:8f:2c:78:86:a2:cf:02:40:7d:9d:3c you@yourhost (DSA)
   ```

   `fd:bc:...` is the fingerprint you are after. If there are multiple keys, multiple lines will be printed, and the last line contains the fingerprint of the last loaded key.
4. If you want to stop the agent (i.e., if you invoked step 1 above), then simply type `exit' on the shell, and you'll be back on the shell prior to the loading of ssh agent.

I do not add new information, but hopefully this answer is clear to users of all levels.

Comment: The first paragraph is untrue, `ssh-add -l` and `ssh-keygen -l` return the same fingerprint for a given keypair.  Also, it should be a lowercase `-l`, not uppercase.

Comment: I don't contest that `ssh-add -l` and `ssh-keygen -l` return the same fingerprint for a given keypair. But I don't understand what was wrong with my original statements on first paragraph. I added a sentence to clarify.

Comment: It's just simper to point ssh-keygen to a key, rather than start the agent, then load the key, then get the fingerprint.

Comment: If you have the private key only, you do not necessarily need to run `ssh-agent`. Assuming `PRIVKEY` has been set to the private key file, and `PUBKEY` has been set to the (initially nonexistent) public key file, do: `ssh-keygen -y -f "${PRIVKEY}" > "${PUBKEY}"` to regenerate the SSH public key, then `ssh-keygen -E md5 -l -v -f "${PUBKEY}"` if you want the MD5 hash or just `ssh-keygen -l -v -f "${PUBKEY}"` if you want the SHA-256 hash (SHA-256 being the default now).

Answer (score 19):

Reproducing content from AWS [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=386670) here, because I found it useful to my use case - I wanted to check which of my keys matched ones I had imported into AWS

`openssl pkey -in ~/.ssh/ec2/primary.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c`

Where:

- `primary.pem` is the private key to check

Note that this gives a different fingerprint from the one computed by `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: I think it'd be important to mention that this doesn't compute the same fingerprint that ssh-keygen would.

Comment: Thanks, done. Tweak it if you like, of course. I'll probably flag these comments for deletion after a while.

Answer (score 14):

The fastest way if your keys are in an SSH agent:

```
$ ssh-add -L | ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf /dev/stdin
```

Each key in the agent will be printed as:

```
4096 MD5:8f:c9:dc:40:ec:9e:dc:65:74:f7:20:c1:29:d1:e8:5a /Users/cmcginty/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Comment: Needed a quicker way to match my keys against those on my GitHub account and this answer helped me do just that.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

will also work on [Mac OS X v10.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) - [v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite).

It also supports the option `-E` to specify the fingerprint format so in case MD5 is needed (it's often used, e.g. by GitHub), just add `-E md5` to the command.

Comment: +1 for the simplest answer. From `man ssh-add` the option `-l` is  " Lists fingerprints of all identities currently represented by the agent"

Answer (score 8):

On Windows, if you're running [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY)/Pageant, the fingerprint is listed when you load your PuTTY (.ppk) key into Pageant. It is pretty useful in case you forget which one you're using.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sometimes us Linux people forget about windows, especially as the OP mentioned putty.

Comment: @DmitriR117 why did you paint black public key as it can be known to the whole world?

Comment: I guess there's always been a little bit of...Paranoia :) What if the quants can use it against me one day?!

Answer (score 7):

This is the shell function I use to get my SSH key finger print for creating [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) droplets:

```bash
fingerprint() {
    pubkeypath="$1"
    ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf "$pubkeypath" | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -c 5-
}
```

Put it in your `~/.bashrc`, source it, and then you can get the finger print as so:

```
$ fingerprint ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
d2:47:0a:87:30:a0:c0:df:6b:42:19:55:b4:f3:09:b9
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you can have a bunch of keys in your `~/.ssh` directory, and don't know which matches the fingerprint shown by GitHub/Gitlab/etc.

Here's how to show the key filenames and MD5 fingerprints of all the keys in your `~/.ssh` directory:

```sh
cd ~/.ssh
find . -type f -exec printf "\n{}\n" \; -exec ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf {} \;
```

(For what the parameters mean, refer to [this answer about the `find` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory/10523492#10523492).

Note that the private/public files that belong to one key have the same fingerprint, so you'll see duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

If your SSH agent is running, it is

```
ssh-add -l
```

to list RSA fingerprints of all identities, or `-L` for listing public keys.

If your agent is not running, try:

```bash
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -l'
```

And for your public keys:

```bash
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -L'
```

If you get the message: '*The agent has no identities.*', then you have to generate your RSA key by `ssh-keygen` first.

Comment: I installed openssh, then attempted to connect to the server using putty. It's presenting an ssh-ed25519 256 key fingerprint, but I'm getting the "no identities" message. Do you know where this key could be found and listed? Is there a downside to using this key, vs generating a new RSA key?

Comment: Found it under `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub`. Second part of the question remains: any downside to using this auto generated key?

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine shows the SSH host key fingerprint in the serial output of a Linux instance. The API can get that data from GCE, and there is no need to log in to the instance.

I didn't find it anywhere else but from the serial output. I think the fingerprint should be in some more programmer-friendly place.

However, it seems that it depends on the type of an instance. I am using instances of Debian 7 (Wheezy) f1-micro.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obtain that from the **private key** do it:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f key > key.pub && ssh-keygen -lf key.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

for bash:
When your keys are not in a file
(when getting pub-keys from a vault)

```bash
echo -n "ssh-rsa AAA....." | ssh-keygen -E sha256 -lf /dev/stdin
echo -n "ssh-ed25519 AAA....." | ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score -2):

To check a remote SSH server prior to the first connection, you can give a look at [www.server-stats.net/ssh/](http://www.server-stats.net/ssh/) to see all SHH keys for the server, as well as from when the key is known.

That's not like an SSL certificate, but definitely a must-do before connecting to any SSH server for the first time.

Comment: User wasn't looking for a third-party website, but a command line from the OS itself.

Comment: So, it's basically the [convergence plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_(SSL)), except for SSH instead of SSL, and with only one (somewhat iffy) notary. That sound about right?

Answer (score -4):

On Fedora I do `locate ~/.ssh` which tells me keys are at

```
/root/.ssh
/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: The OP seems to know where to find their keys (This is not it, `~/.ssh/id*.pub` is) and want to get their fingerprints.