# Execute command on all files in a directory

Tags: bash, scripting

Could somebody please provide the code to do the following:
Assume there is a directory of files, all of which need to be run through a program. The program outputs the results to standard out. I need a script that will go into a directory, execute the command on each file, and concat the output into one big output file.

For instance, to run the command on 1 file:

```
$ cmd [option] [filename] > results.out
```

Comment: I would like to add to the question. Can it be done using xargs? e.g., 
`ls <directory> | xargs cmd [options] {filenames put in here automatically by xargs} [more arguments] > results.out`

Comment: It can, but you probably [don't want to use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to drive `xargs`. If `cmd` is at all competently written, perhaps you can simply do `cmd <wildcard>`.

Answer (score 619, accepted):

The following bash code will pass $file to command where $file will represent every file in /dir

```
for file in /dir/*
do
  cmd [option] "$file" >> results.out
done
```

Example

```
el@defiant ~/foo $ touch foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt
el@defiant ~/foo $ for i in *.txt; do echo "hello $i"; done
hello bar.txt
hello baz.txt
hello foo.txt
```

Comment: If no files exist in `/dir/`, then the loop still runs once with a value of '*' for `$file`, which may be undesirable. To avoid this, enable nullglob for the duration of the loop.  Add this line before the loop `shopt -s nullglob` and this line after the loop `shopt -u nullglob #revert nullglob back to it's normal default state`.

Comment: If the output file is the same inside the loop, it's much more efficient to redirect outside the loop `done >results.out` (and probably then you can overwrite instead of append, like I have assumed here).

Comment: How do you get individual results files which are custom named to their input files?

Comment: @TimothySwan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash

Comment: But how do u sequence which file to execute first, second, third because you can generally run few commands from various files in any order. Order / sequence matters.

Comment: be carefull by using this command for huge amount of files in dir. Use find -exec instead.

Comment: "be carefull by using this command for huge amount of files in dir. Use find -exec instead". But why?

Comment: How would I do it if I want one command for all files joined by space? Like `cmd file1 f2 f3` etc. The files come from a dir.

Comment: @Timo The `xargs` solutions on this page typically do that pretty well.

Answer (score 262):

How about this:

```
find /some/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cmd option {} \; > results.out
```

- `-maxdepth 1` argument prevents find from recursively descending into
  any subdirectories.  (If you want such nested directories to get processed, you can omit this.)
- `-type -f` specifies that only plain files will be processed.
- `-exec cmd option {}` tells it to run `cmd` with the specified `option` for each file found, with the filename substituted for `{}`
- `\;` denotes the end of the command.
- Finally, the output from all the individual `cmd` executions is redirected to
  `results.out`

However, if you care about the order in which the files are processed, you
might be better off writing a loop.  I think `find` processes the files
in inode order (though I could be wrong about that), which may not be what
you want.

Comment: This is the correct way to process files. Using a for loop is error-prone due to many reasons. Also sorting can be done by using other commands such as `stat` and `sort`, which of-course dependes on what is sorting criteria.

Comment: if I wanted to run two commands how would I link them after the `-exec` option? Do i have to wrap them in single quotes or something?

Comment: `find` is always the best option cause you can filter by file name pattern with option `-name` and you can do it in a single command.

Comment: @frei the answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043896/1243247 but basically just add `-exec` options: `find . -name "*.txt" -exec echo {} \; -exec grep banana {} \;`

Comment: how can you reference the file name as option?

Comment: chaining `-exec` commands together works fine as long as the first `-exec` exits succesfully. if it fails, second `-exec` won't run. @Toskan the filename is referenced as `{}`.

Comment: In a recursive search, without the -maxdepth agrument, if I run a command that produces a file (e.g. convert) how do I keep the new files in the same folder as the original? Also, how do I limit the search to a particular file type?

Comment: @Do To that's what `-type` is for, or if you mean file type as hinted by extensions in the name then the answer was already posted above with `-name`.

Answer (score 133):

I'm doing this on my Raspberry Pi from the commandline by running:

```
for i in ./*; do cmd "$i"; done
```

Comment: While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523492/114558) is probably the "right" way to do this in a production environment, for day-to-day usage convenience, this one-liner wins!

Comment: If one wants to use the modified filename as an argument (e.g. for the name of the output file), you can add anything after the `$i` part, and you will have a new string. Example of an imaginary command `ppp -i raw.txt -o processed.txt` would be: `for i in *; do ppp -i "$i" -o "$i changed"; done` - this will do the `ppp` command on every file and the resulting file for each execution will be named like the input file, with addition of " changed" at the end.

Comment: You want `for i in ./*` to avoid the pesky corner case where `*` expands to a string which looks like a command option (which it will if you have files whose name starts with a dash; this is uncommon, but not as uncommon as you'd hope).

Comment: @tripleee Good catch, modified original post.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `xarg`:

```sh
ls | xargs -L 1 -d '\n' your-desired-command
```

- `-L 1` causes pass 1 item at a time
- `-d '\n'` splits the output of `ls` based on new line.

Comment: Using xargs is nice because it allows you to run your-desired-command in parallel if you add the `-P 8` flag (up to 8 processes at the same time).

Comment: For macOS, the `-d` option isn't available. You can fix it by `brew install findutils` first and then use `gxargs` instead of `xargs`

Comment: As noted earlier in my comment on the question, you almost certainly [don't want to use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to drive `xargs`. If you have GNU `xargs`, you can do `printf '%s\0' * | xargs -r0 cmd` but the `-0` option is not in POSIX, and not avaliable e.g. on Mac. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 20):

The accepted/high-voted answers are great, but they are lacking a few nitty-gritty details. This post covers the cases on how to better handle when the shell path-name expansion (glob) fails, when filenames contain embedded newlines/dash symbols and moving the command output re-direction out of the for-loop when writing the results to a file.

When running the shell glob expansion using `*` there is a possibility for the expansion to fail if there are *no* files present in the directory and an un-expanded glob string will be passed to the command to be run, which could have undesirable results. The `bash` shell provides an extended shell option for this using `nullglob`. So the loop basically becomes as follows inside the directory containing your files

```
 shopt -s nullglob

 for file in ./*; do
     cmdToRun [option] -- "$file"
 done
```

This lets you safely exit the for loop when the expression `./*` doesn't return any files (if the directory is empty)

or in a POSIX compliant way (`nullglob` is `bash` specific)

```
 for file in ./*; do
     [ -f "$file" ] || continue
     cmdToRun [option] -- "$file"
 done
```

This lets you go inside the loop when the expression fails for once and the condition `[ -f "$file" ]` check if the un-expanded string `./*` is a valid filename in that directory, which wouldn't be. So on this condition failure, using `continue` we resume back to the `for` loop which won't run subsequently.

Also note the usage of `--` just before passing the file name argument. This is needed because as noted previously, the shell filenames can contain dashes anywhere in the filename. Some of the shell commands interpret that and treat them as a command option when the name are *not* quoted properly and executes the command thinking if the flag is provided.

The `--` signals the end of command line options in that case which means, the command shouldn't parse any strings beyond this point as command flags but only as filenames.

---

Double-quoting the filenames properly solves the cases when the names contain glob characters or white-spaces. But *nix filenames can also contain newlines in them. So we de-limit filenames with the only character that cannot be part of a valid filename - the null byte (`\0`). Since `bash` internally uses `C` style strings in which the null bytes are used to indicate the end of string, it is the right candidate for this.

So using the `printf` option of shell to delimit files with this NULL byte using the `-d` option of `read` command, we can do below

```
( shopt -s nullglob; printf '%s\0' ./* ) | while read -rd '' file; do
    cmdToRun [option] -- "$file"
done
```

The `nullglob` and the `printf` are wrapped around `(..)` which means they are basically run in a sub-shell (child shell), because to avoid the `nullglob` option to reflect on the parent shell, once the command exits.  The `-d ''` option of `read` command is *not* POSIX compliant, so needs a `bash` shell for this to be done. Using `find` command this can be done as

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    cmdToRun [option] -- "$file"
done < <(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

For `find` implementations that don't support `-print0` (other than the GNU and the FreeBSD implementations), this can be emulated using `printf`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec printf '%s\0' {} \; | xargs -0 cmdToRun [option] --
```

---

Another important fix is to move the re-direction out of the for-loop to reduce a high number of file I/O. When used inside the loop, the shell has to execute system-calls twice for each iteration of the for-loop, once for opening and once for closing the file descriptor associated with the file. This will become a bottle-neck on your performance for running large iterations. Recommended suggestion would be to move it outside the loop.

Extending the above code with this fixes, you could do

```
( shopt -s nullglob; printf '%s\0' ./* ) | while read -rd '' file; do
    cmdToRun [option] -- "$file"
done > results.out
```

which will basically put the contents of your command for each iteration of your file input to stdout and when the loop ends, open the target file once for writing the contents of the stdout and saving it. The equivalent `find` version of the same would be

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    cmdToRun [option] -- "$file"
done < <(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) > results.out
```

Comment: +1 for checking that the file exists. If searching in a non existing dir, $file contains the regex string "/invald_dir/*" not a valid filename.

Answer (score 6):

One quick and dirty way which gets the job done sometimes is:

```
find directory/ | xargs  Command
```

For example to find number of lines in all files in the current directory, you can do:

```
find . | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: @Hubert Why do you have newlines in your filenames?!

Comment: it's not a question of "why", it's a question of correctness – filenames don't have to include printable characters, they don't even have to be valid UTF-8 sequences. Also, what's a newline is very much encoding dependent, one encodings ♀ is another's newline. See code page 437

Comment: cmon, really? this does work 99.9% of the time, and he did say "quick and dirty"

Comment: I am not fan of "quick and dirty" (AKA "broken") Bash scripts. Sooner or later it ends in things like famous "Moved `~/.local/share/steam`. Ran steam. It deleted everything on system owned by user." bug report.

Comment: This also won't work with files that have spaces in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jim Lewis's approach:

Here is a quick solution using `find` and also sorting files by their modification date:

```
$ find  directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -r0 stat -c "%y %n" | \
  sort | cut -d' ' -f4- | \
  xargs -d "\n" -I{} cmd -op1 {}
```

For sorting see:

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5720/find-files-and-list-them-sorted-by-modification-time

Comment: this will not work if the files have newlines in their names

Comment: @HubertKario  You may want to read more about `-print0` for `find` and `-0` for `xargs` which use null character instead of any whitespace ( including newlines ).

Comment: yes, using `-print0` is something that helps, but the whole pipeline needs to use something like this, and `sort` isn't

Answer (score 1):

**I needed to copy all .md files from one directory into another, so here is what I did.**

`for i in **/*.md;do mkdir -p ../docs/"$i" && rm -r ../docs/"$i" && cp "$i" "../docs/$i" && echo "$i -> ../docs/$i"; done`

**Which is pretty hard to read, so lets break it down.**

first cd into the directory with your files,

`for i in **/*.md;` for each file in your pattern

`mkdir -p ../docs/"$i"`make that directory in a docs folder outside of folder containing your files. Which creates an extra folder with the same name as that file.

`rm -r ../docs/"$i"` remove the extra folder that is created as a result of `mkdir -p`

`cp "$i" "../docs/$i"` Copy the actual file

`echo "$i -> ../docs/$i"` Echo what you did

`; done` Live happily ever after

Comment: Note: for `**` to work, the `globstar` shell option needs to be set: `shopt -s globstar`

Answer (score 1):

### Maxdepth

I found it works nicely with *[Jim Lewis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523492/4058484)* just add a bit like this:

```
$ export DIR=/path/dir && cd $DIR && chmod -R +x *
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' -exec {} \; > results.out
```

### Sort Order

If you want to execute in sort order, modify it like this:

```
$ export DIR=/path/dir && cd $DIR && chmod -R +x *
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.sh' | sort | bash > results.out
```

Just for an example, this will execute with following order:

```
bash: 1: ./assets/main.sh
bash: 2: ./builder/clean.sh
bash: 3: ./builder/concept/compose.sh
bash: 4: ./builder/concept/market.sh
bash: 5: ./builder/concept/services.sh
bash: 6: ./builder/curl.sh
bash: 7: ./builder/identity.sh
bash: 8: ./concept/compose.sh
bash: 9: ./concept/market.sh
bash: 10: ./concept/services.sh
bash: 11: ./product/compose.sh
bash: 12: ./product/market.sh
bash: 13: ./product/services.sh
bash: 14: ./xferlog.sh
```

### Unlimited Depth

If you want to execute in unlimited depth by certain condition, you can use this:

```
export DIR=/path/dir && cd $DIR && chmod -R +x *
find . -type f -name '*.sh' | sort | bash > results.out
```

then put on top of each files in the child directories like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ "$(dirname `pwd`)" == $DIR ]] && echo "Executing `realpath $0`.." || return
```

and somewhere in the body of parent file:

```
if <a condition is matched>
then
    #execute child files
    export DIR=`pwd`
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hate bash more than YAML configuration files, you can try the [tool](https://github.com/capyfile/capyfile) I've written.

1. Write a config:

```
---
version: '1.2'
name: files
processors:
  - name: cmd_each
    operations:
      - name: filesystem_input_read
        params:
          target:
            sourceType: env_var
            source: INPUT_READ_TARGET
      - name: command_exec
        maxPacketSize: 10
        params:
          commandName:
            sourceType: value
            source: cmd
          commandArgs:
            sourceType: value
            source: ["{{.AbsolutePath}}"]
```

2. Run:

```
INPUT_READ_TARGET=/dir/* capycmd -c -f files.pipeline.yml files:cmd_each
```

Advantages:

- zero code written on bash
- can do such stuff concurrently

Disadvantages:

- you won't see the stdout (can be fixed thought)

Comment: It would be more weird to find someone who doesn't hate YAML more than they hate Bash.

Answer (score -2):

i think the simple solution is:

```
sh /dir/* > ./result.txt
```

Comment: Did you understand the question correctly? This will merely try to run each file in the directory through the shell - as if it were a script.