# archive regenerating shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I need  to create a shell program which generates special "archives". These archives will also be shell scripts, so that they can be executed with "sh ".

Let's say I have some directory structure like:

```
mydir
 +- file.txt
  +- mysubdir
   +- foo.txt
```

file.txt contains "lorem ipsum" and foo.txt contains "foo bar".

Then executing the archive program:

$ arch.sh mydir > bundle.sh

Should generate a file named "bundle.sh" which may look something like this:

```
if [ \! -d mydir ] ; then
mkdir mydir
cd mydir
if [ -f file.txt ] ; then
touch file.txt
echo "lorem ipsum" >> file.txt
fi
if [ \! -d mysubdir ] ; then
mkdir mysubdir
cd mysubdir
if [ -f foo.txt ] ; then
  touch foo.txt
  echo "foo bar" >> foo.txt
fi
fi
fi
```

So, basically, if you would execute this bundle script then you would end up with exactly the same directory structure and file contents that you had when you generated the bundle. Now, only need to write a
program which iterates over all the files and directories and creates
the appropriate output for each. For text files, you could process them
with sed to convert every line in the text file to a shell command.
For example, if the file looks like this:

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
Goo
```

Then you could generate the following shell commands:

```
echo "Foo" >> example.txt
echo "Bar" >> example.txt
echo "Baz" >> example.txt
echo "Goo" >> example.txt
```

For binary files, you should use "uuencode" or maybe you can also use
"base64", e.g. when you have a binary file "file.bin" then executing the
following commands output a shell script which recreates the binary file:

```
base64 file.bin | sed 's/.*/echo\ \0 >> file.txt/g'
echo "base64 -d file.txt > file.bin"
echo "rm file.txt"
```

So in this way, I can just email the bundle.sh commands to a friend, and then when he executes bundle.sh on his machine, he will generate exactly the same directory structure as, say, mydir.

I want to know how to do the recursion to traverse the directory and how to get the name of each file and how to bundle all the shell commands that I generated to bundle.sh. Thanks. guys.

Comment: Is it an option to create `.tar` file, and include it in your script?

Comment: Do you actually have to write this program (for homework, perhaps), or do you just need to generate such a script? You have essentially described the `shar` utility.

Comment: this is an assignment, I need to generate this script, but in order to do so, I'll need another script to get the structure and contents info. about the directory that I'll bundle up. thanks

Comment: cannot use .tar file, can only email texts, like commands.

Comment: @YongfengZhang: You can `base64` your `tar` archive so you can email it. It seems to me same like using `base64` for binary files in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Using [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/) :

```
$ cd /path/to/dir
$ ls 
main.sh dir1 dir2 dir3
$ makeself . ../bundle.run "Creating a bundle with makeself" ./main.sh
```

`main.sh` is the main script. The bundle will contains the full recursive dirs and your main script.

To run the bundle :

```
chmod +x bundle.run
./bundle.run
```