# Take filename as password value in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have multiple password protected files in a directory eg:

```
file123.dat
file456.dat
file789.dat etc
```

I will be writing a script in linux to extract them with their passwords.
each file has its own filename as password how can i extract the names of the files and put them in the script?
**NOTE**:the password are certain alphabets from the filename and not the entire filename
I am using 7zip to extract the file. The script i am using now is :

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=`ls *.zip | xargs -r`
for FILE in $FILES; do
PASSWD=`echo $FILE | awk '{print substr($0,1,2)}'`
`echo abc``echo $FILE | awk '{print       substr($0,5,2)}'`

7za X -p $PASSWD $Z_FILE //using 7zip to unzip
if [ $? = 0 ]; then # successful unzip
break
fi
done
done
```

Comment: Give us an example of how it's store that data into the files...

Comment: What do you extract with, zip, [bzip2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2) or [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats)? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash Script to Execute Command on All Files in Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=`ls *.dat | xargs -r`
for FILE in $FILES; do
    PASSWD=`echo $FILE | sed 's/.dat//'`
     ## extract file $FILE using password $PASSWD
done
```

Comment: 1) Don't parse `ls`: just use `for FILE in *.dat; do`. 2) Don't use `sed` when the parameter expansion `PASSWD=${FILE%.dat}` does the same thing.

Comment: and don't use backticks and don't use uppercase variable names.

Comment: When i try to extract the files with the above code it does not work any suggestions