# execute a program on all files in a directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Could any body hel me?I want to execute a program on all files in a directory in ubuntu 10, the basic command line:

```
~/directory$ ./program -c program.config -f my.flp -p pfolder/i.ptrace -steady_file tfolder/i.steady -model_type grid -grid_layer_file my.lcf
```

I read [a question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-directory) 
,but I didn't understand & it's not my answer. The program must be run on i files in pfolder & the result be printed in a file with same name in tfolder. The other flags & option won't change. We have a "directory" that the exe with its files are in it. We have 2 folder named pfolder & tfolder in that directory too, the .ptrace file that are input are in pfolder & the output files are in tfolder. 1.ptrace, 2.ptrace, 3.ptrace .... are in pfolder in the directory, the program must be execute on all ptrace files & the output files must be in tfolder.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but the two ways are explained in anwsers to the related question: `for file in folder; do ...; done` and `find path/to/folder -exec cmd \;`, so it is indeed a duplicate until you explain why it is not. *I didn't understand* is not a valid reason ;-)

Comment: Wild guess, maybe this FAQ is closer to what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash