# Shell/Terminal: Execute a command for all files in a directory using their absolute path

Tags: python, shell, terminal, travis-ci

I'm trying to execute a command for each file in a directory but while using their absolute path (such as `/home/richi/mydir/myfile.py`) instead of their relative path (such as `myfile.py`).

In other words, I want to execute a command on files in a directory based on their absolute path - similar to `for file in *.py; do thecommand -a "$file"; done` but not quite.

I'm asking this because I'm trying to implement a Travis CI script running in an Ubuntu 14.04 environment which will install and use `pyminifier` to recursively minify all the Python code files in a directory.

> Please note that I'm asking may be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory) post but it's not.

Comment: What do you know about these files? do you have a list by absolute path? Do you need to search through with `find /` through your whole filesystem?

Comment: I need to find the files in a directory - I've updated paragraph 2 in the question to answer that.

Comment: so... `for file in *.py; do thecommand -a "$PWD$file"; done`?

Comment: You've got Windows filenames but bash script syntax, so… does that mean you have a full MinGW setup, with a `realpath` command? If so, just call `$(realpath "$file")`.

Comment: The windows filenames is a mere prop but I'll update my question to fix that.

Comment: If you don't have that, you do presumably have Python, so worst case  you can `$(python -c 'import os,sys; print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))' "$file"`.

Comment: OK, so if you're not on Windows, what platform _are_ you on, what shell are you using, and you do have a full standard userland?

Comment: As I described in the question, I'm using Travis CI. Sorry for my lack in information

Comment: Travis CI is neither a platform nor a shell nor a userland. It runs jobs in whatever container or VM you want. If you run the job in, say, a stock Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS container, that's completely different from running it in, say, the macOS that comes with a Travis "Xcode" container.

Comment: At any rate, if you can't answer any of these questions, you can at least try it. Do you have a `realpath` command? Does it do what you want? If not, what do you want that it isn't doing?

Comment: Forget about Travis CI, just take in these specs: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I think it has `realpath` beacuse of [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/utils/realpath) on Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Your `for` loop very definitely *doesn't* do anything with full paths.

Comment: We've sorted out this question already - see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on a standard Linux distro with a full userland, you can just use the [`realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) command:

> Print the resolved absolute file name…

For example:

```
$ pwd
/home/abarnert/src/test
$ touch 1
$ realpath 1
/home/abarnert/src/test/1
```

That's it.

If you don't know how to use that from within `bash`, you can call a subcommand using `$(…)` syntax:

```
$ echo $(realpath 1)
/home/abarnert/src/test/1
```

Of course you want to pass it the value of the variable `file`, but that's just as easy:

```
$ file=1
$ echo $(realpath "$file")
/home/abarnert/src/test/1
```

I'm assuming you're using bash here. With a different sh-style shell, things will be different; with tcsh or zsh or fish or something, it may be even more different.

---

A really old userland, or a really stripped down one (e.g., for an embedded system) might not include `realpath`. In that case, you can use [`readlink`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink), since the GNU version, as usually, adds everything including a couple kitchen sinks, and can be used as a `realpath` substitute.

Or, if worst comes to worst, Python has come with a [`realpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) function since 2.2:

```
$(python -c 'import os,sys; print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))' "$file")
```

Comment: Interesting... I'm going to see if Travis CI will run it.

Comment: I made the [changes](https://github.com/Richienb/ROS-Code/blob/ea29b195d5c170cf4402332cef9261d49c92b0da/.travis.yml#L69) and it [works](https://travis-ci.org/Richienb/ROS-Code/jobs/406502839)! Thank you for your help.