# Run a single command for every files in a folder- LINUX

Tags: linux

I'm a new Linux user and I'm trying to run a single command for every file in a folder (let's call it Tesi).
In this folder there are 4000 files and I want to create a new column in each one and put in there the relative file name (later I will merge them all).

I've tried this command, but it doesn't work:

```
for i in Tesi; do sed -i "s/$/\t$f/" $f; done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Bash script to execute command on all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523415/608639), [Linux command: find files and run command on them](https://superuser.com/q/566198/173513), [for loop for running a command for all files in a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167896/56041), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this solution would be easier:

```
find <path> -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i "s/\$/\t\$f/" '{}' \;
```

If you omit or increase `-maxdepth` the command will search in subfolders too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer