# Unix script to replace old date with current date dynamically in multiple files present in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to work on a script where it is a *(star) delimited file has a multiple lines starts with DTP. I want to substring the date part and compare with today's date. If it is older than today, I want to replace with today's date. Here is an example.

```
$ cat temp.txt
RTG*888*TD8*20180201-20180201~
TWW*888*RD8*20180201-20180201~
RTG*888*TD8*20180201-20180201~
KCG*888*TD8*20180201-20180201~
```

I want the output as below by changing date. Please help. I am looking for UNIX script to make it work for all files present in that directory

```
RTG*888*TD8*20190424-20190424~
TWW*888*RD8*20180201-20180201~
RTG*888*TD8*20190424-20190424~
KCG*888*TD8*20180201-20180201~
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? And, why are dates in `TWW*888*RD8*20180201-20180201~` and `KCG*888*TD8*20180201-20180201~` not replaced?

Comment: I am new bee to unix .So i couldn't able to prepare a script .
The line where starts with RTG only should get replaced with current date.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work on systems with Bash and GNU's date utility. Let's do a simple script using "while read" loop:

```
# read the file line by line with fields separated by *
while IFS='*' read -r str1 num str2 date; do
    # if the first field is RTG
    if [ "$str1" = "RTG" ]; then
        # then substitute date with current date string
        curdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
        date="${curdate}-${curdate}~"
    fi
     # print the output
    printf "%s*%s*%s*%s\n" "$str1" "$num" "$str2" "$date"
# in while read loops - the input file is 
# redirected to standard input on the end
done < file.txt
```

> Could you please modify the script you provided to work for all files in directory. That would be very helpful for me .

```
# for all entries in current directory (uses bash globulation settings(!))
for file in *; do
   # check if it's a file
   if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
        # if not, next entry
        continue;
   fi

   # run the script
   while IFS='*' read -r str1 num str2 date; do
        if [ "$str1" = "RTG" ]; then
            curdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
            date="${curdate}-${curdate}~"
        fi
        printf "%s*%s*%s*%s\n" "$str1" "$num" "$str2" "$date"
    done < "$file"

done
```

Comment: Bingo...! Its Worked as expected @ Kamil Cuk.. But how to execute the script for all the files present in particular directory Kindly help.

Comment: for example: `for file in particulardirectory/*; do while IFS='*' read ....... done < "$file"; done`. or `IFS='\n' files=($(find particulardirectory -type f)); for file in "${files[@]}"; do while ..... done <"$file"; done`

Comment: Hey kamil, If i want to replace the date part to current date minus(-) 15 days without comparing the existing date in file .How to do that. can you please help me modifyng this

Comment: So follow up to reading the documentation, specify [man date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html). I think `date '--date=-15days'` could print date minus 15 dates. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Getting an error below 
date: illegal option -- -
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]

Comment: As i am tried , i could not able to modify the script to work it for all files present in directory .. .I kindly request you help me out to modify the script you provided.Please

Comment: Are you on IBM? Mac OS? You tagged `linux`.

Comment: I am using putty in windows server @kamil Cuk

Comment: AIX is not linux. You should remove that tag from you question and tag AIX. [linux date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) is different from [AIX date](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/date.htm) and all other utilities are different too. I have no experience in AIX. Do you have bash shell or some other shell? Try `echo $BASH_VERSION` or similar. You could get `date +%s` to get seconds, substract `15 * 24 * 60 * 60` seconds from it and then display the date using proper format. Or you could install GNU date utility.

Comment: Do you have `awk`? This is possible in `awk` and will work way faster, however I am not enough fluent in it to do it. I would rather advise to ask a new question, with proper tags and show what you've done and tried.

Comment: I will check on it . Could you please help on second part that  i could not able to modify the script to work it for all files present in directory .. .I kindly request you help me out to modify the script you provided

Comment: This is a separate question [bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/bash-script-to-execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: I am very new to this Unix shell scripting so i couldn't able to understand as much in link. Could you please modify the script you provided to work for all files in directory. That would be very helpful for me .

Comment: The script provided is just displaying manipulated data of all files content in black screen. How to write it back to their respective individual files

Comment: Just redirect `while` output, the same you redirect input. You can `done <"$file" | sponge "$file"` or like `done < "$file" > "/tmp/some_temp_file" ; mv /tmp/some_temp_file "$file"`. Don't do `< "$file" > "$file"`, it will not work and you will loose your files (you can't read and write to the same file at the same time...). Ach, I guess you don't have [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge), so use a temporary file and `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your files will not have future dates(as per your samples looks like that), if this is the case then try.

```
awk -v dat="$(date +%Y%m%d)" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="*"
}
{
  split($4,array,"[-~]")
  if(array[1]!=dat){
    array[1]=dat
  }
  if(array[2]!=dat){
    array[2]=dat
  }
  $4=array[1]"-"array[2]"~"
}
1'   Input_file
```