# Remove half the lines of files recursively using sed and wc

Tags: bash, sed, wc

I wonder if there is a way to remove half the lines of a file using `wc` and `sed`.

I can do this:

```
sed -i '50,$d' myfile.txt
```

Which removes lines from 50 to the end of file. I can also do this:

```
wc -l myfile.txt
```

Which returns the number of lines in the file.

But what I really want to do is something like this:

```
wc -l myfile.txt | sed -i '{wc -l result}/2,$d' myfile.txt
```

1. How can I tell `sed` to remove the lines starting from the `wc -l` result divided by 2?
2. How can I do this recursively?

Comment: use `d` to delete lines, `r` command is used to append text from another file... try `sed -i $(( $(wc -l <myfile.txt)/2 + 1 ))',$d' myfile.txt` (note that I'm using `+1` as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were close. Just use a command substitution with arithmetic expansion to get the value of the starting line:

```
startline="$(( $(wc -l <myfile.txt) / 2 ))"
sed -i "$startline"',$d' myfile.txt
```

Or a oneliner:

```
sed -i "$(( $(wc -l <myfile.txt) / 2 ))"',$d' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work but, how can I execute this command for every file in a directory hierarchy recursively?

Comment: I would do `find directory -type f | xargs -d $'\n' -n1 sh -c 'sed -i "$(( $(wc -l <"$1") / 2 )),\$d" "$1"' --` or something along that. I suggest to research that [topic separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory). Or something along `find directory -type f -exec sh -c 'sed "$(( $(wc -l <"$1") / 2 )),\$d" "$1"' -- {} \;`

Comment: This seems to be missing one line unless you add `+ 1` after `/ 2`

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of `head` command:

```
head -n -"$(($(wc -l<file)/2))" file
```

awk is also possible, and with `exit` statement, it could be faster:

```
awk -v t="$(wc -l <file)" 'NR>=t/2{exit}7' file
```

You can get the file by `awk/head ... > newFile` or `cmd > tmp && mv tmp file` to have "in-place" change.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense, reading the file twice (or, as noted by Kent, once and a half) is unavoidable. Perhaps it will be *slightly* more efficient if you use just a single process.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { total=FNR; next }
    FNR>total/2 { exit } 1' myfile.txt myfile.txt
```

Doing this recursively with Awk is slightly painful. If you have GNU Awk, you can use the `-t inline` option, but I'm not sure of its semantics when you read the same file twice. Perhaps just fall back to a temporary output file.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "awk 'NR==FNR { total=FNR; next }
    FNR>total/2 { exit } 1' {} {} >tmp &&
  mv tmp {}" _ \;
```

Comment: in fact, we don't need to read the file 2x, we only need 1.5x