# How to remove all `^M` characters from an iOS project in Mac copied from Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, cmd, character-encoding

I had to clone an iOS project from github in my **Windows**. Then when I copied that project into my **Mac** using a pen drive, the project is no more buildable and many files showing `^M` characters in lines end due to difference of [End of Line Character](http://peterbenjamin.com/seminars/crossplatform/texteol.html) formats in different platform.

**So what is the proper way to make this project buildable on my Mac?**

Comment: You want to invole `fromdos`.  Does mac have this tool available on the command line?

Comment: @selbie no its not available in my Mac

Comment: Which programming language?  Most code will compile just fine with those `^M` chars hanging around. They get treated as whitespace.

Comment: A large hybrid app (Objective-C + Swift) @selbie

Comment: Have you tried compiling with out worrying about it?  What error do you get?  I surmise you won't get any errors compiling code with end-of-line differences.

Comment: dos2unix is what you seek: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dos2unix#default

Comment: Actually project was showing huge number of git diff contents and also vi editors showing unwanted characters at end of line and build failed. I will check and let you know if it happened for eol.

Comment: dos2unix is not present in my Mac.

Comment: You get dos2unix via the brew package installer.

Comment: http://aerostitch.github.io/programming/perl/oneliners/perl-dos2unix_mac2unix.html  (use the dos to unix, not mac to unix script) from that link

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/  (scroll down for the perl and sed scripts)

Comment: @selbie how can I run infile command `tr -d '\r' < input.file > output.file` for all of my files in project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dos2unix`:

```
$ brew install dos2unix
$ dos2unix *.swift
```

Without `dos2unix`:

```
for file in *.swift; do tr -d '\r' < $file > temp && mv temp $file; done
```

Comment: My Mac is restricted to access internet. Is there any work around?

Comment: You can do `tr -d '\r'` to each file (by looping over them). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536655/is-there-any-way-to-use-the-tr-command-in-place and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory for example.

Comment: Can you explain with command that will work infile? I cannot use different output file. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile && mv outfile infile`

Comment: it is not feasible to run this command for all files in my project. Could you please answer with the looping?

Comment: Try  this: `for file in *.swift; do tr -d '\r' < $file > temp && mv temp $file; done`