# How to pipe the output of `ls` to `mplayer`

Tags: linux, pipe

I want to run `mplayer` on all files in a folder, **sorted by size**.

I tried the following commands

```
ls -1S folder | mplayer
ls -1S folder | xargs mplayer
ls -1S folder | xargs -print0 mplayer
```

but none of these are working.

How to do it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute command on all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: I tried "for i in `ls -1S folder`; do mplayer "$i"; done" and got an error because of spaces in the file names

Comment: You can loop over files with spaces; Need some extra scripting; Refer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496

Comment: I need a complete script for that? In other cases there is a one-line solution that works, for example `find . -name "*.py" | xargs grep unittest`

Comment: You should not use `-l` in `ls -lS`

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Then I'd say `ls -1S folder | xargs mplayer` should work. What error message have you got ?

Comment: If you can use zsh, it's just `mplayer folder/*(oL)`

Answer (score 1):

[Don’t parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/3651).

Instead, use e.g. `for` to loop over the files and call `stat` to get the file sizes. To avoid issues with spaces or newlines in filenames, use zero-terminated strings to sort etc.:

```sh
for file in folder/*; do
    printf "%s %s\0" "$(stat -c %s "$file")" "$file"
done \
| sort -z -k1 -t ' ' \
| cut -z -f2- -d ' ' \
| xargs -0 mplayer
```

To call `mplayer` individually for each file (rather than only once, passing all files as arguments), you’ll need to use a `while` loop, and pipe in the above. Unfortunate `|` doesn’t work with `while` (at least I don’t know how), you need to use [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) instead:

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    mplayer "$file"
done < <(
    for file in folder/*; do
        printf "%s %s\0" "$(stat -c %s "$file")" "$file"
    done \
    | sort -z -k1 -t ' ' \
    | cut -z -f2- -d ' '
)
```

Note that the above is Bash code, and uses GNU extensions, it works on Linux but it won’t work without changes e.g. on macOS (BSD `cut` has no `-z` flag, and `stat -c %s` needs to be changed to `stat -f %z`).

Comment: op wants the files sorted by filesize though

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Thanks, I hadn’t paid attention. I think my edit should address OP’s issue now.

Comment: play.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
play.sh: line 3: `done < <('

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I should have said, this is Bash code. It looks like you are running on POSIX shell (dash or similar)?

Comment: Never mind, I will use python. I thought there was a simple solution, but I was wrong. With python, I understand what is going on as well

Comment: Yes, you’d think that working with lists of files would be the one thing that the shell knows how to do well but nope. It’s really quite frustrating. (The code *can* be made to work on POSIX Bourne Shell using fifos or temporary files instead of the process substitution, but that doesn’t really reduce the complexity).

Answer (score 0):

I created a python script to build an executable file for just that I want to do. Here is the complete python code:

```
import os
import re
import sys
import glob

dir_name = sys.argv[1]

# Get a list of files (file paths) in the given directory 
list_of_files = filter( os.path.isfile,
                        glob.glob(dir_name + '/*') )

# Sort list of files in directory by size 
list_of_files = sorted( list_of_files,
                        key =  lambda x: os.stat(x).st_size)

# Iterate over sorted list of files in directory and 
# print them one by one along with size
for elem in list_of_files[::-1]:
    file_size  = os.stat(elem).st_size 
    print(f"mplayer {re.escape(elem)}")
```

You redirect the output to a file and execute this. And voila - `mplayer` plays the files in the order from big to small.