# How can I pass a file argument to my bash script twice and modify the filename

Tags: bash

We have a large number of files in a directory which need to be processed by a program called `process`, which takes two aguments **infile** and **outfile**.

We want to name the **outfile** after **infile** and add a suffix. E.g. for processing a single file, we would do:
`process somefile123 somefile123-processed`

How can we process all files **at once** from the command line?
(This is in a bash command line)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory

Comment: `for f in *; do process "$f" "${f}-processed" & done`

Comment: @cyrus: there is a typo: & should be ;

Comment: @OliverGaida: It looks like a typo, but it's not. This takes into account the requirement "*process all files at once*". To process the files one after the other, you would have to replace `&` with `;`, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As @Cyrus says in the comments, the usual way to do that would be:

```
for f in *; do process "$f" "${f}-processed" & done
```

However, that may be undesirable and lead to a *"thundering herd"* of processes if you have thousands of files, so you might consider **GNU Parallel** which is:

- more controllable,
- can give you progress reports,
- is easier to type

and by default runs one process per CPU core to keep them all busy. So, that would become:

```
parallel process {} {}-processed ::: *
```