# Is there a reason why bash command is not applying to all files in directory?

Tags: bash

I have the following script I made from looking at [Execute command on all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory):

```
find /home/user/test/* -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.conf' -exec /home/user/program --config "{}" \;
```

I have a bunch of `.conf` files in `/home/user/test/` and I would like the program to run on all of these at once. The program is to simulate network traffic so runs constantly until stopped using `Ctrl+C`.

If I manually open new screen sessions and run the command on each of the `.conf` files separately it works fine however I am trying to figure our a way to only run the command once on all the `.conf` files.

The script I wrote should apply to all files but it only seems to load just one. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The program is to simulate network traffic so runs constantly until stopped using Ctrl+C.

There's your problem. `find` does not do parallelism or run anything in the background; it runs the program and waits for it to complete before moving on to the next file.

One option is to invoke the command indirectly through an `sh` shell command line, which allows you to put it in the background with `&`:

```
find ... -exec /bin/sh -c "/home/user/program --config {} &" \;
```

The drawback is that you'll have to manually find and kill each spawned `program` if you want to stop them, or use something like `killall`.

Another option would be GNU `parallel`, which does give you better control over your jobs.

A third option, if you can modify `/home/user/program`, is to implement a flag like `--background` or `--daemonize` which tells it to go into the background straight after launch.

Comment: Gotcha thanks for your help! 

Fortunately the program already has a daemonize flag which I can apply in the find script. If I apply this it should run in the background and can be killed once and restarted correct?

Comment: I would expect so, but it depends on the program.

Answer (score 0):

`find` looks in all of the paths listed as arguments.  Commonly, only one directory is given, but it is valid to specify multiple arguments.  For example,  `find . -print` will list all names in and under the current working directory, and `find alice bob -print` will look in and under `alice` and `bob`.  If either `alice` or `bob` is itself the name of a regular file, that name will simply be printed.  In your case, you are using the shell to expand a `*` glob and executing `find` on all of the names that match the glob `/home/user/test/*`.  That glob does not match any names in which the final component starts with `.` (aka, "dotfiles" or "hidden files"), so you will not see any of those.  You want to omit the glob and just give a single path argument to `find`:

```
find /home/user/test -maxdepth 1 ...
```

so that find will look at everything in and under /home/user/test

Comment: Thanks for the details. I modified the script to the below however I am still having the same trouble. It only seems to pick one of the .conf files and runs the program on that and not the others in the dir

`find /home/user/test -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.conf' -exec /home/user/program --config "{}" \;`

Comment: In the question you say "run on all of these at once".  Are you expecting these to run in parallel?  With `find`, they will execute serially.   You probably want to use a tool like `parallel`, but perhaps it is sufficient to do `find ... -exec sh -c '/home/usr/program --config {} &' \;` or similar.

Comment: Yeah I need it to run in parallel, I just tried your find script mod and it is now working perfectly with `find ... -exec sh -c '/home/usr/program --config {} &' \;` 

One last query, as that script has executed and is running in the background how would I able to stop it?