# Verify the server using the public RSA key

Tags: ssh, winscp

I have the RSA version 2 public key from the server I want to connect to. Where do I save this key so I can verify the identity of the server?

My public key is like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAN7ZZHjhUKjKxU...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Calculate RSA key fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9607295/850848).

See also a [relevant section of WinSCP FAQ on host keys](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey#from_putty).

---

You can execute the `ssh-keygen` on any *nix machine, you have an access to.

Or you can download [Microsoft build of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH). On Windows 10 version 1803 or newer, you already have OpenSSH built-in. On older versions of Windows 10, it can be installed as an optional Windows feature. On older versions of Windows, you can just extract the `ssh-keygen.exe` from a .zip ([latest release](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)), no installation is need.

Comment: Show us a format of the public key you have. Or even a complete public key. It's **public** after all.