# get SHA256 hash of public key

Tags: openssl, sha256, sha, sha2

I have a certificate `mycert.pem` . I got the **public key** of the certificate by command:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in mycert.pem  > pubkey.pem
```

How can I get the SHA256 hash of the public key?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607295/calculate-rsa-key-fingerprint for obtaining the SHA256 of a public key if it's not in a `.pem` file.

Answer (score 18):

You can use ssh-keygen. Convert file format first

```
ssh-keygen -i -m PKCS8 -f pubkey.pem > NEWpubkey.pem
```

Next get the fingerprint

```
ssh-keygen -lf NEWpubkey.pem
```

Get type inference

> 2048 SHA256:hYAU9plz1WZ+H+eZCushetKpeT5RXEnR8e5xsbFWRiU no comment (RSA)

Comment: Hm. Interesting, I don't get the same results via `ssh-keygen` as via `openssl` (or the very clever approach shown by @just-be-happy) — I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 8):

The openssl `-pubkey` outputs the key in PEM format (even if you use `-outform DER`).

Assuming you have a RSA public key, you have to convert the key in DER format (binary) and then get its hash value:

```
 openssl rsa -in pubkey.pem -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256
```

Comment: @Leem Are you sure you executed the command in the same folder where the file `pubkey.pem` was created?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It also output`routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:704`

Comment: Hmm... actually, the problem is the certificate and public key I generated has 0 size. Something wrong there....

Comment: @Leem So this means that the command `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in mycert.pem` didn' t work. Please fix your certificate and give feedback on the command I posted,

Comment: I am fixing it, will get back to you here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try directly decode public key with base64, then pipe to `shasum -a256`or `openssl sha256` to get the hash you want:

```bash
sed '1d;$d' ./pubkey.pem | base64 -D | openssl sha256 # or shasum -a256
```

If you use command question mentioned to output pubkey.pem like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

You need strip first and last line in advance like `sed '1d;$d'`.

Then we use base64 `-d` or `-D` to decode (default to stdout) and pipe to `openssl sha256`.

All in one command:

```bash
sed '1d;$d' <(openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in mycert.pem) | base64 -D | openssl sha256
```

Comment: Heh. Magic! :-) In my case, I didn't have a _full certificate_ — but just the public key! — and `openssl` complained and grumbled but spewed something out. Not by coincidence, it was exactly the same SHA256 as produced with your (adapted) command: `cat mypubkey.pem | sed '1d;$d' | base64 -d | shasum -a256`. (or `sha256sum -b` — same thing). "Hey Ma! No `openssl` command!" 