# How do I derive a SHA256 fingerprint from either a public key or MD5 fingerprint?

Tags: sftp, public-key-encryption, sha256, sap-successfactors, aws-transfer-family

I received a public key generated by "SAP SuccessFactors" from someone who needs to connect to an SFTP, but in order for me to import the public key, I need to provide a SHA256 fingerprint.

Apparently "SAP SuccessFactors" can only produce an MD5 fingerprint.  I've tried running the command

```
ssh-keygen -lf <path>.fakekeyname.pub
```

but I get an error

> fakekeyname.pub is not a public key file

In opening up the public key file, the header says

```
 begin ssh2 public key
```

whereas I'm used to seeing something along the lines of ssh-rsa.

Apologies in advance if this seems immediately obvious, but I would sincerely appreciate some guidance or advice.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though, this is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh-keygen. First you would need to convert the file to pem format first

```
ssh-keygen -i -m PKCS8 -f pubkey.pem > NEWpubkey.pem
Next get the fingerprint
```

and then you can get the sha256 value from it:

```
ssh-keygen -lf NEWpubkey.pem
```

for reference see this post:[get SHA256 hash of public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365327/get-sha256-hash-of-public-key)

Edit: For Pub files this could work `ssh-keygen -E sha256 -lf sample.pub` see [How to Calculate Fingerprint From SSH RSA Public Key in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059782/how-to-calculate-fingerprint-from-ssh-rsa-public-key-in-java)

Comment: Thank you!  I assume though, that in the first instance of .pem you meant .pub?


ssh-keygen -i -m PKCS8 -f pubkey.pub > NEWpubkey.pem

Comment: As per reference its for a pem file not pub file. Depending on your use case can you try to convert the pub file to pem format?