# GitHub : import SSH i cant import ssh key in my github account

Tags: github, ssh

when i want to import my ssh key in github i have This Erorr "**Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format**"

[image: my ssh key]

Comment: In the `~/.ssh` folder, there will be a file that ends with `.pub`. The contents of that file is your public key. For example, mine looks like this: `ssh-ed25519 ... me@my-computer`. Depending on how you generated it, it might start with `ssh-rsa` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with:

```
ssh -P "" -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/github
cat ~/.ssh/github.pub
```

Copy the public key content in your GitHub SSH setting page: this one should work.

One starting with `SHA256:...` looks [like a key *fingerprint*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60080442/6309), not an actual public key.