# Get key signature/fingerprint for GPG Public Key

Tags: gpg-signature

How can I get the key signature from a GPG Public Key?  For example, I need a signature for Spotify's public key here: 
https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey.gpg

Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607295/calculate-rsa-key-fingerprint), but for GPG Keys.

This is as far as I've got:

```
$ gpg pubkey.gpg 
pub  4096R/130D1D45 2019-07-15 Spotify Public Repository Signing Key <tux@spotify.com>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the key, import it, extract the email and run `gpg --fingerprint`.

```
cd ~ 
curl -O https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey.gpg
gpg --import ~/pubkey.gpg
gpg --fingerprint tux@spotify.com
# 2EBF 997C 15BD A244 B6EB  F5D8 4773 BD5E 130D 1D45
```

Comment: Sadly, the fingerprint must be extracted from the longer output of `gpg --fingerprint tux@spotify.com`. If you don't know how a fingerprint looks, this is not good UX. [not your fault - thanks for the hint!]