# Graph API: Listing the Active SAML signing certificates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, saml, azure-service-principal

I am using Postman and the servicePrincipals API to build a list of our SAML signing certificates and their expirations. I have all of the keyCredentials for the appID as well as the preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint for the Active cert. However, I am not finding any API references to tie the active thumbprint to the keyCredentials.

Anyone figured out how to build the tie-ins?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), the property `keyCredentials` will have the value you are looking for.

[Key Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/keycredential?view=graph-rest-1.0) will have the following structure:

```json
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.keyCredential",
  "customKeyIdentifier": "Binary",
  "displayName": "String",
  "endDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "key": "Binary",
  "keyId": "Guid",
  "startDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "type": "String",
  "usage": "String"
}
```

You can get the thumbprint directly when you call "addSelfSignedSigningCertificate" action, Microsoft doesn't provide the thumbprint in other calls. The closest you can get is to provide a 'customKeyIdentifier' or read back the key and derivative the thumbprint by taking the key data and feeding into a tool like openssl.

```bash
openssl pkey -in ~/keyfile -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42248153/5779200

Comment: Where in this do you see the thumbprint?

Comment: You can get the thumbprint directly when you call "addSelfSignedSigningCertificate action", Microsoft doesn't provide the thumbprint in other calls. The closest you can get is to provide a 'customKeyIdentifier' or read back the key and derivative the thumbprint.

Comment: The question is how to get the thumbprint for an existing certificate. If you know how to derivate it, could you add that to your answer?

Comment: Added. If you are using something like bash you can script something like that but if you're on Windows using Powershell to automate this you'll need to install OpenSSL.

Comment: Where does the keyfile come from?

Comment: Key file is the "key" value in the payload response.

Comment: Hey @Noah, sorry, I only saw your reply today. I have not tested your updated answer with regards to calculating the thumbprint from the key yet, but it seems feasible to me. Thank you! Upvoted :-)