# How to push Codes from Remote Server (Rackspace) to bitbucket?

Tags: git, centos, bitbucket

I'm wondering if someone has ever experienced of pushing the codes from a remote server to bitbucket.

My remote server is CentOS and i have an existing codes in there. I logged on to my remote server using putty and I think i managed to set up a git repo there by executing the command below

```
git init
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:my_username/my_git_repo.git
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

but when i tried to execute

```
git push -u origin master
```

An error saying "Permission denied (public key)".

Hopefully someone could point me to the right direction here.  Thanks

Comment: You have to add your centos ssh public key to bitbucket

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828164/how-do-i-access-my-ssh-public-key

Comment: If you dont have one check githubs tutorial about making one https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: There will be similar questions in stackoverflow too.

Comment: You are welcome. I will put in an answer later on.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you don't want to deal with ssh public/private keys generation and management, you can switch to an https url:

```
cd /path/to/my_git_repo
git remote set-url https://yourLogin@bitbucket.org/yourLogin/my_git_repo.git
```

You would then be asked for your BitBucket account password.